# what method should i write in onChange so that the value will display in webpage using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have started learning react but stuck here. i want to print the value in webpage but cant get what method should i put in onChange and please need a explanation also.

```js
class IncrementDecrement extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { a: 0 };
    this.change = this.onIncreased.bind(this);
    this.change = this.onDecreased.bind(this);
  }
  change(event) {
    this.setState({ a: event.target.value });
  }
  onIncreased() {
    this.state.a = this.state.a + 1;
    console.log(this.state.a);
  }
  onDecreased() {
    this.state.a = this.state.a - 1;
    console.log(this.state.a);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="number" value={this.state.a} onChange={this.setState} />
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.onIncreased();
          }}
        >
          Increment
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.onDecreased();
          }}
        >
          Decrement
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<IncrementDecrement />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: looks OK to me. You just need to change `onChange={this.setState}` to `onChange={this.change}`, and also fix the constructor so that the only binding is `this.change = this.change.bind(this)`. (You could avoid the binding if you wrote the `onChange={() => this.change()}`, the same way as you do for the two `onClick` handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following changes:

- Bind the methods correctly in the constructor.
- Set `onChange` to `this.change` and not `this.setState`.
- For updating a piece of state use `this.setState` and don't mutate the state.
- And in the `change` method, coerce the value of the input to a `Number` for increment and decrement operations to work properly.

```js
class IncrementDecrement extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { a: 0 };
    this.change = this.change.bind(this);
    this.onIncreased = this.onIncreased.bind(this);
    this.onDecreased = this.onDecreased.bind(this);
  }
  change(event) {
    this.setState({ a: Number(event.target.value) });
  }
  onIncreased() {
    this.setState({ a: this.state.a + 1 });
  }
  onDecreased() {
    this.setState({ a: this.state.a - 1 });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="number" value={this.state.a} onChange={this.change} />
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.onIncreased();
          }}
        >
          Increment
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.onDecreased();
          }}
        >
          Decrement
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<IncrementDecrement />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
<input type="number" value={this.state.a} onChange={this.setState} />
```

to

```
<input type="number" value={this.state.a} onChange={this.change} />
```

`this.change` is a handler for the `onChange` event which take the value and updates the state.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `onChange={this.change}`. You have this method defined but aren’t using it, instead passing `setState` as if it were an event handler, which it isn't.